# Reload constants (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have module (Rails) that define enum dynamically (Model)

```
def define_enums
  memoized_custom_fields.select { |o| o.field_type == 'selectbox' }.each do |o|
    enum o.name.to_sym => Hash[o.additional_data.lines.map { |v| [v, v] }]
  end
end
```

`memoized_custom_fields` I retrive from DB, but when I make changes in DB I can't reload Model (I also can't redefine enum)

Can I "reload" model programmatically?

Comment: If I understand question correctly: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/reload

Comment: Alex Holubenko, I need reload constant (Class) not a loaded object (entity) via active record

Comment: That is a very twisted / advanced way of dealing with a model. What is inside a model is a skeleton for data handling. I am not sure this can be dynamically changed or if this good practice. To me you should reload the whole app in order for changed to take effect but this probably devoid what you are trying to achieve.